# How can an end client discover services registered in Eureka service registry?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Our team is in process of registering a dozen of microservices in Eureka service registry. None of our microservices talk to each other. My team is under impression that our end client applications can use service discovery to efficiently query our services.
I am having hard time to explain the team that service registry is meant to be used by another microservice in same application boundary which can discover which service is up and functional so that it can discover and possibly load balance at its own level before making a query to another service.

As an POC, we have setup Eureka servers in two different zones, and registered one of the microservices in both the zone. We have also setup cluster mode so that eureka servers on those zones can replicate their registry

The question is
a) Is it even useful to go to service registry route when none of our microservices talk to each other?
b) How can be our client applications even be aware of those services registered in registry when they may be running in different zone, may be written in different language and may be owned by other teams? They are simply consuming our REST apis.
I understand it is more of a guidance question rather than solving specific problem. But, I appreciate any insight so that I can correct myself if I have any misunderstanding about Eureka service registry.

Comment: For discovery to be useful, clients would need to be eureka clients. If they are mobile phones or remote browsers, it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an API Gateway like Netflix Zuul, Spring Cloud Gateway or any other framework.
With this, you can avoid the clients to interact with your service discovery.

It also makes the Service Discovery useful, since the API Gateway needs it to forward to the incoming requests the target microservice location.

Remember that a microservice architecture gives the ability for you to multiply the number of available instances of a certain microservice with great ease. The API Gateway uses the Service Discovery to know where the microservice is located and load balance through all the available instances (usually using Ribbon or other client load-balancer framework).

The API Gateway gives other functionalities, like:

- Make your clients to interact with only a couple of microservices, instead of them knowing all your microservice registry
- Set some rate limiting rules so that your clients don't overflow your system
- If needed, they can transform the clients request before forwarding the to the microservice (or after receive the response). For example, you can have clients to send the request in a different format that the microservice is not prepared for.
- You can have different API Gateways for different clients

For more information, go to the following website about microservices in general: https://microservices.io/

This website also contains information about the API Gateway pattern: https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html